# getting error ESOCKETTIMEDOUT in node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using library url-metadata https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-metadata for parsing out urls. I am passing ten URLs to it, one after another.

```
urlList.forEach((element) => {
  urlMetadata(element)
    .then(
      (metadata) => {
        let urlMetaOb = new URLMeta(metadata["og:title"], metadata["description"], metadata["og:image"], metadata["og:url"]);
        urlParseData.push(urlMetaOb);
      },
      (error) => { // failure handler
        logger.warn(`${element} ${error}`);
      },
    )
```

A few URLs are getting an `ESOCKETTIMEOUT` response error. I have already visited solutions related to `ESOCKETTIMEOUT` and implemented 
`process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 128;`, but there was no effect.

How should I implement getting metadata for all urls?

Comment: What's a sample URL that's giving you `ESOCKETTIMEOUT`? It may just be that a server you're trying to connect to is not responding in a timely manner, in which case there's nothing _you_ can do about it.

Comment: Server is connected , I can confirm that.

Comment: If you have environmental issues preventing socket connections from happening without timeouts, it's pretty unlikely we'll be able to help. Sounds like you might need  to do some investigation on your servers and network.

Comment: I don't think so